# Setup STOMP client in plain java spring

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket

I am looking for a STOMP example to write server and client both in java spring. Please someone provide me a good simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Spring Framework does not come with a native Java STOMP client yet, only the server side is provided so far. It is well documented here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp

It seems like there will be a native Java STOMP client in the upcoming Spring Framework 4.2 release (currently due to date is July 1st 2015). It is available in the snapshot already. Just take a look at https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11588

There is a link to the commit adding the STOMP client functionality done by Rossen Stoyanchev.

If you want some examples you can take a look at the tests provided, e.g. *WebSocketStompClientIntegrationTests.java*.

I hope this helps to get started.